# Batch oilify in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I'm pretty new to image editing. I want to be able to batch oilify a number of images. However, I can't find a GUI option in GIMP to do this.

In the filters menu there is a Batch process.. option, but this only allows for basic operations such as resizing, cropping, and so on.

Is there a way I can do a batch process from within a GUI? If this is not possible, is there some command line, or script method I could use?

Comment: @pbs: Sounds like a good case for [answering your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), then.

Comment: @pbs if that worked for you, would you mind posting it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most user-friendly solution I found to this problem was to use the BIMP plugin for GIMP. Here is the [link](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259). (does that rhyme?)

In Linux/Ubuntu, download the BIMP zip file from [here](http://www.alessandrofrancesconi.it/projects/bimp/), unzip it to a location of your choice. Next open a terminal and go to this directory. You need to install some pre-requisites first:

```
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev
sudo apt-get isntall libpcre3-dev
```

Next, you can install BIMP by typing

```
make && sudo make install
```

Once compiled and installed successfully, the BIMP option is available from the "File" menu in GIMP.